# Why is flutter debugging is working when connected to computer, but downloading and launching the debug apk is not working?

Tags: android, flutter, apk

I want to give a local release of my app to some friends so I tried to send them the debug APK for them to run on their phones but when the APK installs and they try to launch it, it will go directly to settings or simply not open.

```
name: raydeo
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: "none"

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.6 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  bloc: ^7.1.0
  equatable: ^2.0.3
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  http: ^0.13.5
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  intl_phone_field: ^3.1.0
  firebase_core: ^1.20.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.6.2
  otp_text_field: ^1.1.3
  hive: ^2.2.3
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  mqtt5_client: ^3.3.1
  hive_generator: ^1.1.3
  build_runner: ^2.2.0
  flutter_bloc: ^7.3.3
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^4.3.4
  share_plus: ^4.0.10+1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  mockito: ^5.3.0
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

This is the contents of my pubspec.yaml file. My flutter doctor is coming up clean. I am using an M1 mac. If anyone needs any other details please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

i had same issue i closed and restarted the app after install. Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

this issue is debugged apk.

Try this

```
flutter build apk --release
```

if no sound

```
flutter build apk --release --no-sound-null-safety
```

Then find apk file. done!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm still having an issue where I can download the APK, but the open button is grayed out. And when I try to open the app from the icon in the app tray, it redirects to settings on the app's page.